# React Native app with release variant crashes - IOS

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, mobile

I'm trying to debug the release variant of my app, with the following command:

`yarn ios --configuration Release`

And the app crashes after the splash screen, without an error message.

I already executed `pod install`  to install the native dependencies.

Does anyone already have this problem?

Comment: Is this happening after installing on an actual device?

Comment: @ShmiliBreuer I'm building the app with the variant release in the xcode workspace and testing with a simulator.